# What's the difference between the "bit-depth" and "color-depth" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The tag [bit-depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-depth) has 60 questions, 7 this year, and [color-depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/color-depth) has 74 and 10.

Neither tag has any description.

What is the difference?

(Why there are so many tags with no description is a more significant question, but let's ignore that for this one.)

Comment: color-depth is specifically for colour, bit-depth has multiple uses, like audio bit-depth (how many bits per sample)

Comment: bit-depth in python for instance could reference to the bit-depth of images. It doesnt have to relate to color.

Comment: greyscale perhaps?

Comment: https://minhajulhaque.com/understanding-bit-depth-color-depth-color-gamut/ Bit depth appears to measure how many possible colors (including shades) an image has been saved with. Color depth is how many possible colors (including shades) a display device is capable of producing. So you could have a 32bit image displayed on a 8bit color display. You would miss out on a lot of information, of course. They are different, even if they are used interchangeably by layfolk.

Comment: To answer your second question, lots of tags are created every day on a huge site like this. So it's practically impossible to keep track of all them.

Comment: The comments are providing information here, in this one question.  Wouldn't it be far better for that information to be added to the description of these tags so everyone can benefit?

Comment: Sure, go for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As people have commented already, [bit-depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit-depth) is a more general term than [color-depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/color-depth). Whereas color depth is the number of bits per pixel, any attribute that is digitized has a bit depth, which is the number of bits per sample. Audio and voltage measurements are just two examples.

In practical usage on Stack Overflow, there is almost certainly some overlap between the two tags, but I don't see any compelling reason to remove one or the other tag.

> (Why there are so many tags with no description is a more significant question, but let's ignore that for this one.)

The reason is actually quite simple: the description must be manually composed and submitted by users. It doesn't happen automatically. So, if no one creates and submits a tag description, there won't be one available. Note that anyone can submit tag descriptions as part of the suggested edit system. The submissions will be reviewed by other community members, and, if approved, will go live. For tips on writing a good tag wiki excerpt, please see [this blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/). In particular, note that a good tag wiki excerpt should not define the word/concept, but rather *describe when/how the tag should be used on Stack Overflow*.